# how to avoid change file extension from index.html to index.html.bak.bak on a2hosting

Tags: malware

My hosting server is getting infected by a malware. It renames my index.html to index.html.bak.bak how can i stop it??
Even after changing all passwords and removed all malicious code, next day again same thing happens.

Comment: 1. We cannot possibly know how some random malware is doing something. 2. The problem is not likely to be your passwords, but a vulnerability in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is an automated script, which changes the file extension. Changing the password isn't solution for this.

Here are the possible ways to get rid of this problem:

1. Use [A2Hosting Malware Cleaning Service](https://www.a2hosting.com/malware-protection)
2. Use third party malware cleaning and protection service such as [Sucuri](https://sucuri.net/website-security/malware-removal/)
3. Hire someone
4. Try some techniques yourself (such as restoring from latest backup or removing unnecessary files) [Do it on your own risk, because could lead to data damage/loss]

There could be a persistent backdoor to control website remotely but very less likely for your case.

Finally, if you are hosting multiple website then make sure; all of them are clean!

Comment: ohk thanks @Atlas i will try it all possible solution.